# Deny access to files without password?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, file, browser

I have a framework that I've written. I created a package for said framework that allows me to track my employee's hours, and gives them a place to dump files for the accountant. (Invoices, etc.)

The problem is that these file dumps are accessible through the browser. I could use a `.htaccess` file to prevent the files from being served up at all, but the problem is that I would like the accountant and the employee to be able to download their files.

A solution might be to read the files with PHP, create a temporary copy, have the user or accountant download that copy, then delete the copy...but this poses two problems.

1) It's going to be time and resource intensive...especially for large files. 

2) For whatever short amount of time, there will be a copy of the file which is accessible to whoever knows the URL.

The other solution would be to put the files outside of the public folder, but the problem is that I would like this package to be portable, and a lot of my servers are shared.

What method could I use to be able to serve the files only when authenticated, and avoid the flaws I described above?

Comment: place out side of root serve with php after login

Comment: @Dagon, I have no idea what you mean by that. And I specified in my question that I'm on shared servers and I would like the package to be portable...meaning the solution must work without having access to anything but the public directory.

Comment: Why has this been downvoted?

Comment: place files out side of web root, or in a directory protected by `.htaccess`. serve the files via a php script, after the user has logged in

Comment: @Dagon, how would one serve a file with PHP?

Comment: This is a bit broad of a question and there's so many ways that you can go about this.

Comment: `readfile()` is the usual approach

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I didn't know any of the solutions, and therefore this is the most specific question I'm capable of asking.

Comment: a little google goes a long way

Comment: Should I delete my question?